# Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename js/app.chunk.js (chunks chunk-2d22497b and chunk-b0a634c6) in vue.config.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vue.js, webpack

My vue project running on production, Now I'm implement vue-mapBox & mapbox-gl on my project. After implementation then face yarn run build errors "Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename js/app.chunk.js (chunks 0 and 1)". I have try many way to solve this problem but locally project run successfully in the case production project not run

> my vue.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        disableHostCheck: true,
        port: '8080'
    },
    chainWebpack: config => {
        if (config.plugins.has('extract-css')) {
            const extractCSSPlugin = config.plugin('extract-css')
            extractCSSPlugin && extractCSSPlugin.tap(() => [{
                filename: 'css/app.css',
                chunkFilename: 'css/app.chunk.css'
            }])
        }
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: false
        },
        output: {
            filename: 'js/app.js',
            chunkFilename: 'js/app.chunk.js'
        }
    }
}
```

I want to these files, not chunks file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFo1H.png)